# Twitter API App Authentication Callback URL has port number appended

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I am trying to link my application with Users twitter accounts using the Twitterizer library within asp.net mvc3. I have specified my callback url within my twitter app settings on their developer page.

```
www.myapp.com/twitterconnect
```

Everything works fine when testing in my local environment(using localhost as the callback)

but when I deploy and try to connect using the real app, the twitter callback URL specifies port 14605, which is apparently being blocked by my host.

www.myapp.com:14605/twitterconnect

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter uses default callback url in case if you haven't passed the one in current request.

So find a way for your twitter API library to specify the callback you need at the moment (or not to pass any callback url at all).

Comment: I have a callback url specified on my application page at dev.twitter.com. Does twitter modify this url if I do not pass one with the request?

Comment: @stephen776: If you do not pass anything - then twitter uses the one you specified on application page. If you **do pass** something via `oauth_callback` parameter - then twitter uses the passed one. Double check that you or your library does send it with port

Comment: Found it, I was passing the port number in the oauth_callback url